# How to separate columns and format date when web scraping by using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am trying to web scrape, by using Python 3, a chart off of this website into a .csv file: [2013-14 NBA National TV Schedule](https://www.sbnation.com/2013/8/6/4595688/2013-14-nba-national-tv-schedule)

The chart starts out like:

```
Game/Time                Network      Matchup
Oct. 29, 8 p.m. ET       TNT          Chicago vs. Miami
Oct. 29, 10:30 p.m. ET   TNT          LA Clippers vs. LA Lakers
```

I am using these packages:

```
import re
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from itertools import groupby
```

I imported the data by:

```
pd.read_html("https://www.sbnation.com/2013/8/6/4595688/2013-14-nba-national-tv-schedule")[0]
```

The output sample is:

```
    0                        1            2
0   Game/Time                Network      Matchup
1   Oct. 29, 8 p.m. ET       TNT          Chicago vs. Miami
2   Oct. 29, 10:30 p.m. ET   TNT          LA Clippers vs. LA Lakers
```

The output I want in a .csv file looks like this:

[image: Output in .csv File]

I am unsure how I can split the game/time up into separate columns. Notice how the date is formatted like 10/29/13. I also am unsure how to split matchup into away (first team) and home (second team) into separate columns. I know `pd.to_datetime` and `str.split()` should be used. How do I implement the scraper to get this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['Date']=df['Date'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

This line should help you format the date in the exact way you want

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_html("https://www.sbnation.com/2013/8/6/4595688/2013-14-nba-national-tv-schedule",header=0)[0]

df['Date']=df['Game/Time'].str.extract(r'(.*),',expand=True)
df['Time']=df['Game/Time'].str.extract(r',(.*) ET',expand=True)
df['Time']=df['Time'].str.replace('p.m.','PM')


df['Date'] = np.where(df.Date.str.startswith(('10/', 11/', '12/')), df.Date + ' 13', df.Date + ' 14')
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Date']=df['Date'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

df['Home'] = df['Matchup'].str.extract('(.*)vs')
df['Away'] = df['Matchup'].str.extract('vs.(.*)')
df = df.drop(columns=['Game/Time','Matchup'])
print(df)

Network        Date       Time           Home           Away
0     TNT  10/29/2013       8 PM       Chicago           Miami
1     TNT  10/29/2013   10:30 PM   LA Clippers       LA Lakers
2     TNT  10/31/2013       8 PM      New York         Chicago
3     TNT  10/31/2013   10:30 PM  Golden State     LA Clippers
4    ESPN  11/01/2013       8 PM         Miami        Brooklyn
```

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my take:

```
df = pd.read_html("https://www.sbnation.com/2013/8/6/4595688/2013-14-nba-national-tv-schedule")[0]

# set the correct column names
df = df.T.set_index([0]).T

# separate date and time
datetime = df['Game/Time'].str.extract('(?P<Date>.*), (?P<Time>.*) ET$')

# extract Home and Away
home_away = df['Matchup'].str.extract('^(?P<Away>.*) vs\. (?P<Home>.*)$')

# join the data
final_df = pd.concat([datetime, home_away, df[['Network']]], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
        Date        Time          Away         Home Network
1    Oct. 29      8 p.m.       Chicago        Miami     TNT
2    Oct. 29  10:30 p.m.   LA Clippers    LA Lakers     TNT
3    Oct. 31      8 p.m.      New York      Chicago     TNT
4    Oct. 31  10:30 p.m.  Golden State  LA Clippers     TNT
5     Nov. 1      8 p.m.         Miami     Brooklyn    ESPN
..       ...         ...           ...          ...     ...
141  Apr. 13      1 p.m.       Chicago     New York     ABC
142  Apr. 15      8 p.m.      New York     Brooklyn     TNT
143  Apr. 15  10:30 p.m.        Denver  LA Clippers     TNT
144  Apr. 16      8 p.m.       Atlanta    Milwaukee    ESPN
145  Apr. 16  10:30 p.m.  Golden State       Denver    ESPN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regex` to split out your columns, your `time` has different format so we can handle those by using specific formats and forcing the errors into NaT values.

```
df = pd.read_html("https://www.sbnation.com/2013/8/6/4595688/2013-14-nba-national-tv-schedule")[0]

# set column
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df.iloc[1:].reset_index(drop=True)

#set date and time column.
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime((df['Game/Time'].str.split(',',expand=True)[0] + ' 2019')
                           ,format='%b. %d %Y')
df['time'] = df['Game/Time'].str.split(',',expand=True)[1]

#time column has different formats, lets handle those.

s = pd.to_datetime(df['time'].str.strip('ET').str.replace('\.','').str.strip(),
               format='%H %p',errors='coerce')

s = s.fillna(pd.to_datetime(df['time'].str.strip('ET').str.replace('\.','').str.strip(),
               format='%H:%M %p',errors='coerce'))

df['time'] = s.dt.time

#home and away columns. 
df['home'] = df['Matchup'].str.extract('(.*)vs(.*)')[0].str.strip()
df['away'] = df['Matchup'].str.extract('(.*)vs(.*)')[1].str.strip('.')
# slice dataframe.
df2 = df[['date','time','home','away','Network']]

print(df2)

0         date      time          home          away Network
0   2019-10-29  08:00:00       Chicago         Miami     TNT
1   2019-10-29  10:30:00   LA Clippers     LA Lakers     TNT
2   2019-10-31  08:00:00      New York       Chicago     TNT
3   2019-10-31  10:30:00  Golden State   LA Clippers     TNT
4   2019-11-01  08:00:00         Miami      Brooklyn    ESPN
..         ...       ...           ...           ...     ...
140 2019-04-13  01:00:00       Chicago      New York     ABC
141 2019-04-15  08:00:00      New York      Brooklyn     TNT
142 2019-04-15  10:30:00        Denver   LA Clippers     TNT
143 2019-04-16  08:00:00       Atlanta     Milwaukee    ESPN
144 2019-04-16  10:30:00  Golden State        Denver    ESPN
```

Comment: I am getting `IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level` on line 15 where `format='%H %p',errors='coerce')`

Comment: @Sunny sorry typo, can you re-check